# How can I text-align the very last line of my div when there is a <br> present?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make so that only the very last line of text is set to `text-align: justify;`

My html looks like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="textbox">Some Text goes here<br><a href=link></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
#textbox {
    text-align: center;
    text-align-last: justify;
}
```

The `<br>` is causing the second-to-last line to be justified, and the link which is the last line is also justified. The problem is that I do not want the second-to-last line to be justified. I only want the very last line be justified.

I have tried to add the following to my CSS:

```
a {
   text-align: justify;
}
```

and removing `text-align-last: justify;` from #textbox but I did not have any luck.

Any recommendations on how I can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a` tag is an inline tag,so you should wrap `a` tag into a block tag,say `p` tag,and then apply justify css style.

If you have to use a tag alone,following is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #textbox {
      -ms-text-align-last: center;
      -moz-text-align-last: center;
      text-align-last: center;
    }
    
    a {
      display: block;
      -ms-text-align-last: justify;
      -moz-text-align-last: justify;
      text-align-last: justify;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="textbox">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore sed magni nesciunt pariatur recusandae quam. Suscipit dolorum, labore exercitationem natus!
      <br>
      <a href="#">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis nulla autem perferendis enim deleniti magnam incidunt, maxime praesentium amet officiis.
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

PS:Instead of using br tag,you should use html semantically,you can use such block tags as p tag to wrap line.

About text-align-last,see [css-tricks text-align-last](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align-last/)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but that still does not solve the problem. I would like there not to be a visible space between the two, hence the reason why I used <br> and not <p></p>

Comment: I have update the code.Please check if it meets your need.

Comment: Glad to help you solve your problem,please vote my answer up.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign this CSS to the the `a` tag:

```
#textbox > a {
  display: block;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
```

Whatever the contents of your link will be (which you didn't specify), in order to justify it, you first need to make it a block element. Then you can justify its contents.

```css
#textbox > a {
  display: block;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="textbox">Some Text goes here<br><a href=link>What is supposed to be here?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```